# How Add or Remove Checkboxes value from the array?

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox, checkboxlist, native-base

i want to **add or remove value** from the array.
when i **select** the checkbox the value will **pushed to array.**
when i **unselect** the checkbox the value will **remove from the array**.

**CheckBox**

```js
<CheckBox
 checked={this.state.currentValue}
onClick={() => this._changeValue(index)}>
```

**onClick function**

```js
_changeValue(value) {
    this.setState({
      currentValue: !this.state.currentValue,
    });
   console.log(value)
   selectedQuesiton.push(value)
  }
```

Comment: can you provide me the code you created ..?

Comment: the code provided already..

Answer (score 0):

this is how i am doing

```js
_changeValue(value) {
   this.setState({
     currentValue: !this.state.currentValue,
   });
   if(selectedQuesiton.includes(value)){
       selectedQuesiton = selectedQuesiton.filter(item => item !== value)
       }
       else{
         selectedQuesiton.push(value)
       }
       console.log(selectedQuesiton)
 }
```

i am using filter to check data is available in the array or not and if it is then 
it will just ignore that item in to new array which selectedQuesiton in your case

hope this works and if it does not then comment me